# Windows driver *.INF how to define multiple USB-Devices

Tags: windows, driver

ю How can I define multiple PIDs in my USB-driver? 
Should I make for each device a new row like this?

```
[DeviceList]
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_***C&PID_0001
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_***C&PID_0002
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_***C&PID_0003

[DeviceList.NTamd64]
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_***C&PID_0001
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_***C&PID_0002
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_***C&PID_0003
```

Or is it possible to define multiple in one row?

```
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_***C&PID_0001&PID_0003
```

I can't find any definitions of `[DeviceList]`. I have opened other drivers, each of them use other names for `[DeviceList]`. Can I use my own name for theese lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a different distinct entry for each device id. In your example the entire string `USB\VID_***C&PID_0001` identifies the device and you can't append by `&` the differences to a single string. `&` is a part of the predefined format which separates different sub-parts of a single device id.

Regarding the `[DeviceList]` - you can't find documentation about this section because it's user-defined in the `[Manufacturer]` section. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: Could you provide an example inf file for multiple devices? I can't seem to get it to work.